# HTML table width not working

Tags: html, css, width, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1" width="100%">

        <tr>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
            <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        </tr>


    </table>




</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to set the table width to 100% for above table but it has no effect it goes beyond window width. how do i change the width of table so it is same size as window.

Comment: You can't fit all that in 100% anyway. So, what did you expect to happen? If you explain what effect you're hoping for, maybe we can help achieve that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is, the content inside your table requires more space than 100% of your window-size offers.

What you could do, is to use the overflow-property of CSS. Try the following example and chose, wether this is an option for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    .table {
        color: green;
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll; <!-- Available options: visible, hidden, scroll, auto -->
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1" class="table">

    <tr>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

There are 4 options available for the overflow-property: visible, hidden, scroll and auto. The above example illustrates the scroll-option, which adds a scroll-bar to the table itself.

Comment: For me, the heart of the solution was  display: block, which overrides display: table. Something about display: table makes long, wrapping columns make the table too wide. CSS is a confusing mess of a design.

Answer (score 23):

There is nothing you can do if the table content is too wide (as in your example), apart from alter the content to make it possible for the browser to show it in a narrower format. Setting `width:100%;` will have no effect if the content is too wide. The browser will just resort to displaying a horizontal scrollbar.

You can make your content more narrow by:

- Reducing the number of columns
- using `CSS white-space: nowrap` on any of the content, so the browser has the option of wrapping that content to keep the width down.
- Reduce any margins, borders, padding that you have
- Reduce the font size
- Use `word-wrap:break-word` or `word-break: break-all;`
- Overflow the content that doesn't fit within the screen's width with `overflow: scroll;` (your options are visible, hidden, scroll and auto)

The browser will avoid the scrollbar if it can, but it won't if the content can't fit within the width of the page.

Comment: There are other things you could do. Change the font size, `word-wrap:break-word` etc. it's even possible to keep the table at 100% but to have the content overflow out of it. I just don't know which of these effects the OP was hoping to achieve.

Comment: I'll also throw in CSS's `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: It would help if you gave an actual example and not just use bullet points.

Comment: Shouldn't CSS be white-space: normal?  I had similar problem where some table header text where wrapped in <span> with white-space: no-wrap.  Nice header formatting for wide screens but prevents width:100% for smaller.

Comment: You can't get a scrollbar with the default display: table.

Answer (score 10):

Just need to apply table-layout: fixed

```css
table {
table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr td {
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
    <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only if what you want is for each column to be the same width.

Answer (score 9):

This surprisingly simple solution did the trick for me.

```
table { width: 100%; }
table td, table th { overflow-wrap: anywhere; }
```

Preview here: https://jsfiddle.net/3m2Lw7d4/

Note: [*overflow-wrap* replaces *word-wrap*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) in official CSS3.

Comment: This is the simplest way, it works fine for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me due to wide, wrapped columns, making the width of the table contents exceed the table width.

Answer (score 3):

You can put an element into the cells - that's what I did.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
        <td><div style="width:200px">YOUR CONTENT</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

For bootstrap wrap your table element with `.table` class in a wrapper `<div>` with the `.table-responsive` class. Try this code. copied form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28339204/2315972)

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work with all versions of Bootstrap, or tested only in one? Did you test with any wide columns?

Answer (score -5):

you can put a class in your table like

```
 <table border="1" class="size" >
```

, and from your css you put

```
  .size{

             width : 100%;

             }
```

and you should put the link of your css between   
like this :

```
<link href="css/YOUR_CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Comment: You should test these things before you post. If you had tested, then you'd have seen this solution has exactly the same problem as the OP's. Even if you corrected the errors in your example.

Comment: Sorry to be frank, But looking at your solution gave me a headache. thanks.

Comment: if you begin in programation, you will see that html and css are in "couple" generaly , it's mean that css class design you html code owing to css code. So , you create a new file with .css and you call this page with the <link> that i pet

Comment: You can pet all you like, but answers here are supposed to have solutions to problems, not provide more problems. After your edit, there's still an error. And like I said, it won't work even without errors!

Comment: Your CSS got wrong syntax. And even so, setting 100% width won't solve the original problem posted in this question. Advising to use CSS instead of inline style or attributes is good, but do that in comment not as an answer.

Comment: What is "programation"?