# Bootstrap table won't fill container width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a web site using bootstrap (3.3.2) with a simple table on one of the pages.  I just have a simple header panel in one container, and another content container with a title and table.  For some reason, text fills the width of the container, but the table left aligns and only spans the width required by the text within.  Anyone have any ideas?  I know I can add in a width="100%" to the table, but this should be default bootstrap behaviour...

Cheers

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="modules.html">Modules</a></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="sites.html">Sites</a></li>
            <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="search.html">Search</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Why won't the table align!?</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Body1</td><td>Body2</td><td>Body3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Body1</td><td>Body2</td><td>Body3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Body1</td><td>Body2</td><td>Body3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add the classes 'table table-responsive' to the table tag and wrapp the <th> tags in your table-header into the <tr> tag!

Answer (score 222, accepted):

It's because you are not following the Bootstrap documentation indications on [responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#tables-responsive). You have to wrap your `table` element with `.table` class in a wrapper `<div>` with the `.table-responsive` class, like this:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll be damned! ... surely i've not done it like that each time??

Comment: This answer is incorrect. According to docs at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables the table-responsive class needs to be placed onto a parent wrapping the table.

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>

Comment: @somecallitblues This answer is quite old, and at time of writing it was different, I will update it.

Answer (score 38):

NOTE: If you're using bootstrap v4 alpha, even though the [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/) says that you can use:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  ...
</table>
```

I still had to use the accepted answer to make it fill the container's width:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is incorrect. Per the docs

> Create responsive tables by **wrapping** any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

Then goes on to show proper usage

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
     ...
   </table>
</div>
```

You should also have the `.table` class on the `<table>`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me:

just add another class into your table element: **`w-100 d-block d-md-table`**

so it would be : **`<table class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">`**

for bootstrap 4 **`w-100`** set the width to 100% **`d-block`** (display: block) and **`d-md-table`** (display: table on min-width: 576px)

```
<div class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
<table class="table">
 ---
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add bootstraps class "table" to the  tag.

```
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th><th>Head3</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Body1</td><td>Body2</td><td>Body3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Body1</td><td>Body2</td><td>Body3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Body1</td><td>Body2</td><td>Body3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Even responsive tables do not expand to fit the container if the container is large. There is no Boostrap table configuration to make that happen.

The simplest way, if you want to use Bootstrap classes, is to add [`w-100`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/).
Otherwise, use a single-column [grid layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Comment: This works if both the content of the table is smaller than the container width, and if the table-responsive class is removed.

Answer (score 2):

In most simple words !!

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any `.table` in `.table-responsive`
>   to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under `768px`). When
>   viewing on anything larger than `768px` wide, you will not see any
>   difference in these tables.

So for your requirement `.table` and `.table-responsive` will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
```

you should use:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hyu08psw/)