# HTML table width issue

Tags: html, html-table, width

I have html table. Code is like below :

```html
<table class="table table-striped pay-bills">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="paybill-row">
      <th style="width:19%;" colspan="2">Contractor</th>
      <th style="width:10%;" colspan="2">All Unpaid Bills</th>
      <th colspan="5">Pay Items</th>
      <th style="width:8%;" rowspan="2">GROSS AMOUNT</th>
      <th colspan="2">Deduction Items</th>
      <th style="width:8%;" rowspan="2">NET AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paybill-row">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Hold</th>
      <th>Pay</th>
      <th> pt2108 </th>
      <th> pt3008 </th>
      <th> pt3108 </th>
      <th>Pay</th>
      <th>GST/ HST</th>

      <th>1105</th>
      <th>105</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As shown in code, 3rd column called 'Pay Items' doesn't have fixed size. Same for 5th column. All other columns are fix size. But now issue is, table's width is not proper, as shown in below image.

[image]

As shown in image, there is some space after last column. How to set that space? As for `<tr>`, width is 100%, though its not showing till last.

Comment: please create a [mcve] withe rendered html and css

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Try using `table-responsive` class on your table

Comment: `table-responsive` is not working

Comment: might depend which version of bootstrap you use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339119/bootstrap-table-wont-fill-container-width